# BlackBerry - Volume saving issue

Tags: blackberry, volume

I am facing problem to store volume level on persistence memory. I am using following code:

```java
int _currentVolume = 50;
```

Code for setting player volume level:

```java
volumeControl = (VolumeControl) _player.getControl("VolumeControl");
volumeControl.setLevel(_currentVolume);
setVolume(_currentVolume);
```

Code for storing volume:

```java
public void Save() {
    StoreInfo info = new StoreInfo();
    info.setElement(StoreInfo.VOL2, String.valueOf(volumeControl.getLevel()));

    _data.addElement(info); 
    synchronized (store) { 
        store.setContents(_data); 
        store.commit(); 
    }
}

public void Get() { 
    synchronized (store) { 
        _data = (Vector) store.getContents(); 

        if (!_data.isEmpty()) { 
            StoreInfo info = (StoreInfo) _data.lastElement();   
        }   
    } 
}
```

But the code  is not working :(. Need some help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see  where you apply `Integer.parseInt((String)StoreInfo.getElement(StoreInfo.VOL2))` to your `_currentVolume`.

Comment: It programs two months ... I do not know everything yet. how do I resolve this?